# Rest API to get template files for the API connection on the logic app

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps, azure-rest-api

I want to get the template files for the API connection by clicking the Export **template button** on the logic app:

[image]

This is one of my API connection for my logic App. When you select it, then in the left nav bar there is a button "Export template". **We could manually export the .zip files, but we want to using REST API to achieve this, so that we could automate this step in the later task.**

However, I could not find the correct REST API to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reproducing from my end, I could get this done using the below REST API.

```
https://management.azure.com:443/subscriptions/<SUBSCRIPTION_ID>/resourceGroups/<RESOURCE_GROUP_NAME>/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/<CONNECTION_NAME>?api-version=2016-06-01
```

You can get the GET REST API directly from the portal. By navigating to your template.

[image]

Results:

[image]

Comment: I achieved my needs by other means, but still thanks for your input, it seems to be correct